# newb question - forward slashes and back slashes grr

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, autoresize

I'm using cakephp. In my users model I allow ppl to upload a pic. Once it uploads ok I save the url of the pic to `$this->data['User']['image_url']` and save it. To upload I use the kind advice given here: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/uploading_files_and_images_with_cakephp

After the upload is done I want to resize the photo so I have a thumbnail. I'm using the advice here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Perkster/2008/04/12/image-resizer-crop

All is ok, except for the value in `$this->data['User']['image_url']` looks like `files/photos/userimage.jpg`

The upload script I'm using seems to be expecting the urls with backslashes rather than forward ones coz when I run it I get the error

```
getimagesize(C:\xampp\htdocs\MyNewSite\app\webroot\img\files/photos\$image_name) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream:
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows. You may want to use [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant, even though it [shouldn't matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058347/newb-question-forward-slashes-and-back-slashes-grr/6058403#6058403).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes are not the problem, the `$image_name` is. It's impossible to tell without seeing the code, but you probably are using single quotes when assigning the file name, leading to the variable not getting parsed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Windows accepts both directory separators `\` and `/`, thus the problem must be somewhere else. This is taken from the error message

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyNewSite\app\webroot\img\files/photos\$image_name
```

I assume, that there is no file `$image_name` ;) It seems, that you didnt let PHP evaluate the variables when calling `getimagesize()`

Comment: I'm a stupid ballix. When I was calling the function I was passing $image_name in single quotation marks. <homer>D'oh</homer> thanks for the help tho.